# Table in a list environment violates pages margins when width is set to \textwidth

Tags: tables, lists

I'd like to have a table in a list (enum) environment. No usually I set the width of my tabularx environment as 1.0\textwidth which gives me a table straight from the left page margin to the right page margin aligning with the text. Now if a do the same within a list environment, I have the intendation of the list which then in combination with the full pagewidth results in a violation of my right page margin.

Is there a proper way to tell my table to fill the page but taking the intendation of the list environment into account?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{p{0.2\textwidth}X}
...
\end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Try `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. You wanna create an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance `\textwidth` is the width of the text block. In many cases this is not the width of the current line, e.g. twocolumn or itemizations. It is often better to use `\linewidth`, which is always the width of the current line. In this case,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \strut
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{p{0.2\textwidth}X}
    Stuff & \lipsum[2]
  \end{tabularx}
\item 
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}[t]{p{0.2\textwidth}X}
    Stuff & \lipsum[2]
  \end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (i) about lengths `textwidth`, `\linewidth` and `hsize` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ctextwidth+%5Clinewidth+%5Chsize, (ii) i would use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{p{0.2\textwidth}X}` (observe `[t]`)

Comment: @Zarko, I agree, it is nicer to have the table aligned with the numbering. I have updated.